# D3 force directed graph direction

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm new to D3, and am trying to make a graph similar to this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2675ff61ea5e063ede2b5d63c08020c7) but a few things confuse me. I'm unsure when the example is referring to things built in to D3, or just the data set they are using.

Like here, I'm not sure about the `id` in `d.id.` as the example's data looks like this, which makes me think id is from the data. Or does it represent an index value?

```
"nodes": [
    {"id": "Myriel", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Napoleon", "group": 1}
         ],
            // etc
"links": [
    {"source": "Napoleon", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mlle.Baptistine", "target": "Myriel", "value": 8},
    {"source": "Mme.Magloire", "target": "Myriel", "value": 10},
          //etc

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; })) <-- where is this from?
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
```

SO! In my code I get an error repeating thousands of times, 'Uncaught Error: missing: X', where X is the value of the first source in my links array. I can console.log my data and it looks fine, and the elements are rendering to the DOM, but all bunched up to the top left of the SVG. I don't know what is wrong. I guess I have 2 questions.

1. Could someone clarify about the example id thing?
2. What does my error mean?

Any help would be appreciated.

My code;

```
var graph

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");


d3.json("./mock.json", function(json) {
  var graph = json
      console.log(graph);
      console.log(graph.nodes);

      var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
      .force("link", d3.forceLink(graph.links))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width/2, height/2));

  var link = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    //.attr("stroke-width", function(d) {return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      //.attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.id); })
      .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended));

    node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) {return d.text });

    simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

    simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

})

function ticked() {

  link
      .attr("x1", function(d) {return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) {return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) {return d.target.y; })

  node
      .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y; });
}


function dragstarted(d) {
    if(!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
}
function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
}
function dragended(d) {
    if(!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
}

});
```

Data:

```
{
 "nodes":[
         {"reference":5, "year": 0, "text":"The amount of time spent on video gaming is related negatively to academic achievement", "tags":["Academic disturbance"]},
         {"reference":5, "year": 0, "text":"Digital addiction ranges from <1% and 38%", "tags":["Addiction"]},
         {"reference":58, "year": 0, "text":"Patological video game play impacts negativelly academic achievement", "tags":["Addiction"]},
         {"reference":77, "year": 2009, "text":"74% of adults have Internet access at home", "tags":["Adults"]},
         {"reference":64, "year": 0, "text":"Apathetic users spend short times on web pages, follow no logical order, and make random selections", "tags":["Apathetic hypertext users3"]},
         {"reference":8, "year": 0, "text":"49.8% of sessions are shorter than 5 seconds", "tags":["App usage"]}
       ],
 "links": [
       {"source":0,"target":2},
       {"source":0,"target":6},
       {"source":1,"target":6},
       {"source":1,"target":3},
       {"source":1,"target":2}

 ]
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. The index of `6`, see in your `links` array, is not available in the `nodes` array. `nodes` has a length of 6, which means the largest index is `5`. This causes an error even with the correct code. I have change `6` to `5` in my working example below, and I believe that is what you want.
2. Since the links are based on the index, you can simply return the index instead of the ID, i.e. `d3.forceLink().id(function(d,i) { return i; }`.

Here is the proof-of-function example:

```js
var graph

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height");

var json = {
  "nodes": [{
    "reference": 5,
    "year": 0,
    "text": "The amount of time spent on video gaming is related negatively to academic achievement",
    "tags": ["Academic disturbance"]
  }, {
    "reference": 5,
    "year": 0,
    "text": "Digital addiction ranges from <1% and 38%",
    "tags": ["Addiction"]
  }, {
    "reference": 58,
    "year": 0,
    "text": "Patological video game play impacts negativelly academic achievement",
    "tags": ["Addiction"]
  }, {
    "reference": 77,
    "year": 2009,
    "text": "74% of adults have Internet access at home",
    "tags": ["Adults"]
  }, {
    "reference": 64,
    "year": 0,
    "text": "Apathetic users spend short times on web pages, follow no logical order, and make random selections",
    "tags": ["Apathetic hypertext users3"]
  }, {
    "reference": 8,
    "year": 0,
    "text": "49.8% of sessions are shorter than 5 seconds",
    "tags": ["App usage"]
  }],
  "links": [{
      "source": 0,
      "target": 2
    }, {
      "source": 0,
      "target": 5
    }, {
      "source": 1,
      "target": 5
    }, {
      "source": 1,
      "target": 3
    }, {
      "source": 1,
      "target": 2
    }

  ]
};

var graph = json;

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d, i) {
    return i;
  }))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

var link = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "links")
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(graph.links)
  .enter().append("line")
  //.attr("stroke-width", function(d) {return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

var node = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  //.attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.id); })
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended));

node.append("title")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.text
  });

simulation
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .on("tick", ticked);

simulation.force("link")
  .links(graph.links);


function ticked() {

  link
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    })

  node
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
}


function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
```

```css
.links line {
  stroke: #aaa;
}

.nodes circle {
  pointer-events: all;
  stroke: none;
  stroke-width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.8/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="200"></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Looking back on my question it is a bit of a mess! I probably should have split it in two. Regarding my links referring to an index (6) which didn't exist, that was an error in my haste to simplify my actual, 1000s-of-lines-long, data. So while I'm not sure that was the issue I had at the time, your second point led me to the right track.

Comment: @damtypo I can totally understand. It is sometimes difficult to reduce your issue into an easily digestible one that can be used on SO, but I think you did a great job at describing your issue. I did believe that the index `6` is merely a typo, because you explicitly and clearly stated that it's the `.id()` method that is giving you issues ;)